# Names being entered by the user during a for loop are overwriting themselves in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am trying to write a program in C that allows the user to enter names until they input the word "done". Then it will list out all the names they have entered. I understand I should use an array of pointers to accomplish this and then use a while loop to keep entering names and then put the pointer into the array after they enter the name. The problem is that once I go to print out the names, all the names are equal to whatever I entered last.

I wrote a simpler program that does something similar to what I am doing and encounters the same problem. Here is the code for that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char* first;
    char* second;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        char enteredName[20];
        printf("%s", "Please enter a name: ");
        scanf("%s", enteredName);

        if (i == 0)
        {
            first = enteredName;
        }
        else
        {
            second = enteredName;
        }
    }
    printf("First: %s\n", first);
    printf("Second: %s\n", second);
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
Please enter a name: john
Please enter a name: carl
First: carl
Second: carl
```

What I believe is happening is that both the first and second variables are pointing to the same spot in memory and so they just say the same thing. How would I fix this while still using a loop to enter an arbitrary number of names?

Comment: Correct. You're not copying the string. You're only copying a pointer to the string. On top of this, the memory you're pointing to is not even in scope by the time you use the pointers, and so you have Undefined Behavior. The fact that your program prints any "sensible" string at all is down to pure luck.

Comment: You should clarify what "arbitrary number of names" really means in the context of your program. It might be that you only need to store some maximum number of names and so something like a 2D array might be fine: `char names[N][20];` where `N` is the maximum needed. Or you might use dynamic allocation (_i.e._ `malloc`) to create memory and copy the strings as required: `char *names[N];` If you really want "arbitrary" count you'll need a dynamically-growable array (_e.g._ `realloc`): `char **names;` or implement a linked list.

Comment: Yet another option is to store all the strings in a single char buffer which you grow as required. In this program, I don't see the need for direct indexing, so you could just iterate through the buffer and output names as you encounter them. _e.g._ your buffer might look in memory like `"john\0carl\0"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I believe is happening is that both the first and second
> variables are pointing to the same spot in memory and so they just say
> the same thing.

Yes it is correct. pointer only holds the reference (address) of the object. Your pointers are pointing (referencing) the same array.

> How would I fix this while still using a loop to enter
> an arbitrary number of names?

You need to copy the strings to the memory allocated and assigned to the pointers

```
        if (i == 0)
        {
            first = malloc(strlen(enteredName) + 1);
            if(first) strcpy(first, enteredName);
        }
        else
        {
            second = malloc(strlen(enteredName) + 1);
            if(second) strcpy(second, enteredName);
        }
```

Comment: Alternatively, use `strdup`.

Comment: Beware that strdup is not part of the standard until C23, but a POSIX extension.